# Python HTTP socket : not always receiving everything from client with a JSON sent

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sockets, http

I've been coding a server socket in python which is able to receive HTTP request from a client with a JSON payload attached to it  and display it on the server side. The problem is that sometimes (not regularly) I don't receive the JSON , only the HTTP header (cf. code and example of output below)

With my colleague we've spent a entire afternoon to solve this problem without success, so we would be grateful is someone have a tips or has already encountered such a problem and solved it.

Here is the server

```
import socket, queue, select

HOST=''
PORT=20400


class Socket_Serv:  
    def creaSocket(self, SocketHTTP=None):
        if SocketHTTP is None:
            self.SocketHTTP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.SocketHTTP.setblocking(0)
        else:
            self.SocketHTTP = SocketHTTP
    def listening(self,HOST,PORT):
        self.SocketHTTP.bind((HOST, PORT))
        self.SocketHTTP.listen(10)
        print("Listening on port : {}".format(PORT))
    

    def recept(self):
        inputs=[self.SocketHTTP]
        outputs=[]
        message_queue = {}
        while inputs:
            print ('\n Waiting for message')
            rfile, wfile, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
            for sock in rfile:
                if sock is self.SocketHTTP:
                    connection, client_addr = sock.accept()
                    print ('Connection from'), client_addr
                    connection.setblocking(0)
                    inputs.append(connection)

                    message_queue[connection] = queue.Queue()
                else:
                    msg_recu = sock.recv(400)
                    if msg_recu:
                        msg_test = msg_recu.decode()
                        print(len(msg_test))
                        if len(msg_test) <= 400:
                            print ('received "%s" from %s' % (msg_recu, sock.getpeername()))
                            message_queue[sock].put(msg_recu)
                            if sock not in outputs:
                                outputs.append(sock)
                        else : 
                            print ('closing', client_addr, 'after wrong length')
                            if sock in outputs:
                                outputs.remove(sock)
                            inputs.remove(sock)
                            sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)
                            sock.close()
                    else :
                        print ('closing', client_addr, 'after reading no data')
                        if sock in outputs:
                            outputs.remove(sock)
                        inputs.remove(sock)
                        sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)
                        del message_queue[sock]
            for sock in wfile:
                try:
                    next_msg= message_queue[sock].get_nowait()
                except queue.Empty:
                    print ('output queue for', sock.getpeername(), 'is empty')
                    outputs.remove(sock)
                else:
                    print ('Envoi OK to %s', sock.getpeername())
                    sock.send(b"OK_OK")
                    print("Ecriture finie")
                    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
                    outputs.remove(sock)
                    sock.close()
                    Socket.recept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Socket= Socket_Serv()
    Socket.creaSocket()
    Socket.listening(HOST,PORT)
    Socket.recept()
```

Here is the part of the client which is sending the request

```
POST_DATA = (json.dumps({ "IP":internal_info.Get_ip() ,"version":VERSION , "UTC_TIME":str(internal_info.Get_time()) , "UUID":str(myuuid) })).encode("ascii")
        print(POST_DATA)
         try :
            with urllib.request.urlopen(ip,POST_DATA) as f :
                print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
        except (urllib.error.URLError,http.client.HTTPException,ConnectionError) :
            print("HTTPError")
        finally:
            print("no")
```

And here is the example of output

```
Connection from

 Waiting for message
322
received "b'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 130\r\nHost: X.X.X.X:20400\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/3.7\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n{"IP": "X.X.X.X", "version": "1.1", "UTC_TIME": "2020-09-23 12:39:46.396360", "UUID": "dcc549c2-fd99-11ea-8c16-000c29102f8a"}'" from ('X.X.X.X', 60416)

 Waiting for message
Envoi OK to %s ('X.X.X.X', 60416)
Ecriture finie

 Waiting for message
Connection from

 Waiting for message
192
received "b'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 130\r\nHost: X.X.X.X:20400\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/3.7\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'" from ('X.X.X.X', 60418)

 Waiting for message
Envoi OK to %s ('X.X.X.X', 60418)
Ecriture finie

 Waiting for message
Connection from

 Waiting for message
192
received "b'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 130\r\nHost: X.X.X..56:20400\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/3.7\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'" from ('X.X.X..23', 60420)

 Waiting for message
Envoi OK to %s ('X.X.X..23', 60420)
Ecriture finie

 Waiting for message
Connection from

 Waiting for message
322
received "b'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 130\r\nHost: X.X.X..56:20400\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/3.7\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n{"IP": "X.X.X..23", "version": "1.1", "UTC_TIME": "2020-09-23 12:39:48.473513", "UUID": "ddfd343a-fd99-11ea-8c16-000c29102f8a"}'" from ('X.X.X..23', 60422)

 Waiting for message
Envoi OK to %s ('X.X.X..23', 60422)
Ecriture finie

 Waiting for message
Connection from

 Waiting for message
322
received "b'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 130\r\nHost: X.X.X..56:20400\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/3.7\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n{"IP": "X.X.X..23", "version": "1.1", "UTC_TIME": "2020-09-23 12:39:50.540748", "UUID": "df3dae38-fd99-11ea-8c16-000c29102f8a"}'" from ('X.X.X..23', 60424)

 Waiting for message
Envoi OK to %s ('X.X.X..23', 60424)
Ecriture finie
```

As you can see sometimes I receive everything sometimes not and there is no logic in the behavior of the output. First, we thought about a buffer problem but because of the non-regularity it probably isn't the solution. We've tried many other way to send the data such as using requests lib but the output is the same.
Besides the fact that I'm pretty new to python, without error on the server during the execution it's pretty hard to troubleshot it.

Comment: Your server isn't speaking HTTP at all, i.e. no proper processing of HTTP request and invalid HTTP response. Also you seem to assume that a single `recv` will always read the full "message". This is the wrong assumption. TCP is only a byte stream and has no inherent message semantics. You need to properly implement HTTP, i.e. read the HTTP, then read the body until you've got the advertised length, then reply with a proper HTTP response.

Comment: I see, I will search for an other way to implement HTTP then. Thanks for the clarification